# Elaborar um programa em C que receba 6 numeros inteiros e em seguida o programa devera apresentar a soma destes numeros na tela, so consegui ate aqui

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int N1, N2, N3;

    printf("Digite o primeiro numero: ", N1);
    scanf("%d", &N1);
    printf("Digite o segundo numero: ", N2);
    scanf("%d", &N2);
    printf("Digite o terceiro numero: ", N3);
    scanf("%d", &N3);



    system("PAUSE>>NULL");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida? Você só sabe ler 3 números? Ou consegue aproveitar esse conhecimento e ler os 6 necessários? Você tem problemas com operações aritméticas e por o resultado delas em uma variável?

Comment: Olha esse problema você pode resolver utilizando estruturas de repetição

Comment: Reforço o que o @JeffersonQuesado disse. Qual é exatamente a sua duvida ? Ficou a faltar dizer isso, que é o mais importante.

Answer (score -2):

Está ai o código corrigido, qualquer dúvida estou aqui

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int numero, somatorio = 0; //iniciar com zero para não ter lixo de memória
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&numero);
    somatorio+=numero;  // vai somar todos os numeros que o usuario digitar
  }
   printf("%d\n",somatorio);  // mostra o resultado
   return 0;
}
```